# How fix character encoding in R plots?

Tags: r, plot, character-encoding

Recently, I installed R with anaconda. Apparently, everything works fine. However, when I plot something strange boxes with numbers appear instead of the letters and numbers.
I think that I have a problem with character encoding.

How can I fix this problem?
I attach a sample plot with my problem.

[image]

my sessionInfo() output is:

```
R version 3.6.1 (2019-07-05)

 Platform: x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu (64-bit)

 Running under: Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS

 Matrix products: default
 BLAS/LAPACK: /home/marco/anaconda3/envs/Rstudio/lib/R/lib/libRblas.so
 
 locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=es_MX.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               
 LC_TIME=es_MX.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=es_MX.UTF-8    

 [5] LC_MONETARY=es_MX.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=es_MX.UTF-8   
 LC_PAPER=es_MX.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 

 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C             
 LC_MEASUREMENT=es_MX.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

 attached base packages:
 [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     
 
 other attached packages:
 [1] geometry_0.4.5               QuantumPhaseEstimation_0.1.0

 loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] compiler_3.6.1   rsconnect_0.8.17 tools_3.6.1      abind_1.4-5       yaml_2.2.1       Rcpp_1.0.6       pracma_2.3.3    
 [8] magic_1.5-9
```

Also, I found that I can not install Cairo library

```
checking for ATS font support in Cairo... no
configure: CAIRO_LIBS=-lcairo
checking for library containing deflate... -lz
checking whether Cairo programs can be compiled... configure: error: Cannot compile a simple Cairo program. See config.log for details.
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘Cairo’
```

Comment: which character set does the text that you wanna show in your plot use ? while creating your plot specialize with `iconv`

Comment: If possible, please edit your question to include the output of `sessionInfo()`

Comment: More likely is the possibility that your R installation has a set of fonts as the default that is different than what you have on your Ubuntu setup. Look at ?points (in a console session) for examples of changing fonts.

Comment: I solved the problem. I installed cairoDevice using the anaconda navigator! Thanks.